# Java static class members and Scala interoperability

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

From the An *Overview of the Scala Programming Language, Second Edition*:

```
// Scala
object PrintOptions {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        System.out.println("Options selected:")
        for (val arg <- args)
            if (arg.startsWith("-"))
                System.out.println(" " + arg.substring(1))
    }
}
```

> In the example above, the Scala program invokes methods `startsWith`
>   and `substring` of `String`, which is a class defined in Java. It
>   also accesses the static `out` field of the Java class `System`, and
>   invokes its (overloaded) `println` method. This is possible even
>   though Scala does not have a concept of static class members. In fact,
>   every Java class **is seen in Scala** as two entities, a class
>   containing all dynamic members and a singleton object, containing all
>   static members.

I understand translation of Scala's companion objects into Java bytecode, but I am not sure what exactly does it means bold text in upper blockquote "**is seen in Scala**" for opposite example (from Java to Scala).

Does it mean that Java classes with static members are actually converted or just interpreted as two entities in Scala? Or both of my assumptions are wrong?

Comment: Related to your edit: And the question is? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be blinded by Java assumptions. Consider this simple snippet of code:

```
X.Y()
```

The means that the method `Y` is being called on the object `X`, or on some other object which `X` was implicitly converted into.

Maybe that doesn't look surprising, or you don't see anything amiss with that, so let's state explicitly a consequence: **X will *NEVER* be a class**. You don't invoke methods on classes, period.

Naturally, that presents a serious interoperability problem with Java regarding static members, and that's why it is stated that static members of a Java class `X` will be "seen" as a singleton object: because, otherwise, you'll never be able to use them.

Note that Scala's singleton objects are true objects -- they are instances of singleton classes. Java classes with static members will not give origin to single objects, though. In practice, this means that this line:

```
val x = X
```

will work if `X` is a Scala singleton object, but won't work if it is a Java class with static members.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that scala doesn't change anything to the initial java code, where static members and non-static members are in the same class.

Thus your second assumption is true, the first one is false.

I guess the book use **seen** instead of **interpreted** because this last one can have a different meaning if you think about "interpreted languages" (which are meaningless in that context).